# Raspbian: start program from .sh file

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to do this:

- Execute an executable from a .sh file
- Keep this executable open in terminal

I tried to write a .sh file with "./program" but "program" closes automatically after flashing a console, but I want that terminal to keep open!

Comment: do an infinite while loop: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-infinite-loop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are in a graphical environment, and want to execute a script by double-clicking the ".sh" file, then keep the terminal window open to see any result.

At the end of your script, add something like this :

```
echo "Hit the [return] key to exit"
read
```

This will cause execution to pause until you hit [return].

Note : you cannot keep a program running when it has finished executing.  So the program you are calling from your script finishes, but then you give the terminal (which is also a program) something to do (waiting for input) to prevent it from closing.

Comment: it's the same, even adding "read" at the end the terminal disappears without even waiting for my imput

Comment: Can you explain how you execute this script, and what it contains?  Does it have execute permission?

Comment: I just click on the script file without "sudo" permission, I wrote a .sh file  with just the "lxterminal" command to see if it could open the raspbian shell.

I saw that the command "lxterminal" works when I write it in the terminal but it doesn't work when I save it in a .sh file.

Even when I wrote "read" in the .sh file it just flashed a shell and immediately disappeared